# How do I generate a discount coupon in Magento for a specific store from an outside web app?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, web-applications, coupon

I am currently developing a web app system which would need to generate discount coupons for a specified web store. Currently, my system is written in JS.

What I would want to do is the following:

When the store owner clicks a button on my web app, it will grab information entered and generate a discount on their magento store.

How could I do this?

Comment: Use magento API

Comment: Would I be able to use it in an application/website that is not on a magento store? @Tom

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_extend_magento_rest_api.html